# having the same gradle level still throws fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I am facing this error while gradle building

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

despite all my google versions are same

app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.iviewlabs.mrmint"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'

}
```

while my project level gradle is

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
} 
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Please help me find the solution I have tried many solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. in **app.gradle**

   ```
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
   ```

**ADD THIS LINE AT THE END NOT AT THE TOP AS YOU HAVE DONE.**

like this:-

```
     dependencies {
     }
     apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: You need build plugin `3.0.1` to use `implementation` instead of `compile`. Having latest Play services library is not relevant. Please remove both of these points from your answer. The only important bit is the first step.

Comment: Cool , i thot of updating the whole answer ...according to the latest updates , is it fyn now ? @EugenPechanec